# Why cant java find symbol even though string is defined?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DJNameCreator {
   public static void main(String[] args){
   
   //Variables to store inputted names
      String firstName;
      String lastName;
   
      //Scanner for user inputted names
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
         
      System.out.println("Please enter your first name: ");
      firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
         
      System.out.println("Nice to meet you, "+firstName+"!");
         
      System.out.println("Please enter your last name: ");
      lastName = keyboard.nextLine();
         
      //Use substring and length method to get total length of string
         
      //First name section
      int firstLength = firstName.length();
            
      if (firstLength%2 == 0){
         String firstHalf = firstName.substring(0, firstLength/2);
      }
            
      //Last name section
      int lastLength = lastName.length();
            
      if (lastLength%2 == 0){
         String lastHalf = lastName.substring((lastLength/2), lastLength);
      }
            
      if (lastLength%2 == 1){
         String lastHalf = lastName.substring((lastLength/2), (lastLength)-1);
      }
      //Output the DJ name using println combined with the word "Jayster"
      System.out.println(firstHalf + "Jayster" + lastHalf);
   }
}
```

I can't figure out why java cannot find symbol. My code compiles fine until the last `println`. It's pointing at `firstHalf` and `lastHalf` specifically. I have them defined in the if statement, but it won't compile.

Is it because if statements are kind of isolated from the main code?

Comment: The term you're looking for is _scope_, and the blocks after the `if` statements (not the `if`s inherently) do form a new scope.

Answer (score 2):

In the snippet above the `firstHalf` and `secondHalf` have scope only in their respective If blocks. Where as you are trying to print it in the method scope of Main.

You can find more info about scopes [here](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/variable-scope-in-java).

Check the refactored code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DJNameCreator {
        public static void main(String[] args){
    
            String firstName;
            String lastName;
    
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    
            System.out.println("Please enter your first name: ");
            firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
    
            System.out.println("Nice to meet you, "+firstName+"!");
    
            System.out.println("Please enter your last name: ");
            lastName = keyboard.nextLine();
    
           
            int firstLength = firstName.length();

             // FirstHalf is in the scope of main method.
            String firstHalf = "";
            if (firstLength%2 == 0){
                 firstHalf= firstName.substring(0, firstLength/2);
            }
    
            
            int lastLength = lastName.length();
            // LastHalf is in the scope of main method.
            String lastHalf ="";
            if (lastLength%2 == 0){
                lastHalf = lastName.substring((lastLength/2), lastLength);
            }
    
            if (lastLength%2 == 1){
                lastHalf = lastName.substring((lastLength/2), (lastLength)-1);
            }
            //Output the DJ name using println combined with the word "Jayster"
            System.out.println(firstHalf + "Jayster" + lastHalf);
        }
    }
```